# DocuSign Status not

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am a newbie to DocuSign integration with SalesFocre. I have DocuSign and Salesforce connected using connect settings, and am sending a DocuSign document from a custom object in salesForce. However, the DocuSign Status and the DocuSign Recipient Status are not populating on the Custom object. DocuSign Customer Support confirmed that my connect settings on DocuSign and salesForce  are correct. In the DocuSign logs I can see the "dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c succeeded". But I do not see the same in the related list of the custom object. I can see the DocuSign status object in SalesForce shows all the envelopes but no related list records on custom object. The support person thinks that since the DocuSign integration is done using REST api, she will not be able to investigate the issue any further.
My REST api call is as per the sample code in DocuSign rest api implementation. However I do not know how do we notify the DocuSign of the relationship between the custom object and the envelope? I have not come across any documentation on this. Support person thinks that that might cause this issue. I am on a time crunch and will appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: .@MK2007 - Unless you provide more details with relevant code, examples of what you tried and relevant screenshots, I don't see you getting any help on this. You also need to structure your question [in better way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, In my RESTcall , I first create envelope and using the envelope id that I get in response, I make another request to get the sender's view url. Everything is working fine till this point, except for the fact that the related lists are not being populated. So I did not post my json request and response.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, Do you know if we have to link these requests with custom object in some way so that DocuSign knows which custom Object in SalesForce it's supposed to update with new DocuSign status? DocuSign REST api documentation is for generic use and not specifically for salesForce. I am trying toi figure out if this is configuration issue or is there any extra parameter needed to be sent in rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DocuSign Status and DocuSign Recipient Status aren't populating on the Custom Object in SFDC, I'd suspect that you've missed something in terms of configuration. I'd suggest that you verify that all settings have been configured properly (in both DocuSign and SFDC), as described in this article: https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-add-ds-status-to-custom-object.

---

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comment below that contains a SOAP code snippet, it looks like that snippet is simply adding a ***custom field*** to the Envelope. Do I understand correctly that you're creating the envelope using the REST API?  If so, then the equivalent REST API request to add the custom field when you create the Envelope (in the same manner as your SOAP snippet appears to be doing) would be:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
    "emailSubject": "EMAIL_SUBJECT",
    "emailBlurb": "EMAIL_BLURB",
    ...
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
            { 
                "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                "value": "ID_OF_THE_CUSTOM_OBJECT_IN_SALESFORCE",
                "show": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

***Note:*** I've included the **emailSubject** and **emailBlurb** properties in this request example simply to show that the **customFields** property is a top-level property in the "Create Envelope" request body. Depending upon your implementation specifics, you may or may not be including **emailSubject** and **emailBlurb** in your "Create Envelope" request, and your request will most certainly contain additional properties which I haven't included in the example above. The important take-away here, as it relates to your question, is that in order to add a custom field when creating an Envelope using the REST API, you must include the **customFields** property as a top-level property in the request body, as shown in the example above.

Comment: ,I followed same documentation that you provided in the link, moreover while on DocuSign support call, the support person even checked that all settings are correct. After some research I found the below example for SOAP. Does anyone know how to implement this in REST api?
DocusignNetApi.CustomField field = new DocusignNetApi.CustomField (); 
field.Name = 'DSFSSourceObjectId'; 
field.Value = pCustomObjectId;
field.Show = 'false';
DocusignNetApi.ArrayOfCustomField arrayOfCustomField = new   DocusignNetApi.ArrayOfCustomField();
....
 pEnvelopeInformation.CustomFields = arrayOfCustomField;

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about how to accomplish (with REST) what your SOAP code snippet appears to be doing.

Comment: Brand, thanks for your update. I changed my json as per your suggestion and I can see the SalesForce object id populated in DocuSign logs. Now I hope to see the related list for DocuSign Status on my VisualForce page.

Comment: can you please tell me, for DocuSign Recipient status what should be the name of DSFSSource object? I need to show the docusign recipient status related list as well.

Comment: I figured I do not need any other object and my recipient status related list is populating now. Thanks for your help.